# Can water volume reduce with introduction of another chemical

Tags: water, concentration

Can a chemical be introduced to a volume of water which can actually reduce the volume of water in that container?

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34919/is-there-a-soluble-salt-or-compound-that-when-dissolved-in-water-results-in-a-s

Comment: Mithoron, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23534/is-it-possible-to-have-volumesolution-volumesolvent-volumesolute is not a duplicate because this question is asking can Volume(solution) < Volume(solvent), i.e. there is no term for the solute volume.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least if only the total volume should decrease:

Density of water: $\pu{1000 kg/m^3}$
Density of ethanol: $\pu{789 kg/m^3}$
**Expected** density of 52 Vol.% ethanol solution: $\pu{890 kg/m^3}$
**True** density of 52 Vol.% ethanol solution: $\pu{909 kg/m^3}$
*All values are for the same conditions.*

The volume of every ethanol-water solution is smaller than the sum of the original volumes of water and ethanol. For example if you add $\pu{52 mL}$ of ethanol to $\pu{48 mL}$ water you will get a solution with an volume of approximately $\pu{97.9 mL}$.
This effect is known as **volume contraction** and depends on the mixing ratio of both components in a nonlinear way. Its reason is the formation of additional bonding forces (*e.g.*, hydrogen bridges) between the molecules, which results in a higher density.

*Note:* I don´t think that there is something that can increase density of water in such a way that the resulting total volume is actually smaller than the volume of water used.